# ACF Blocks Output field in header

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a field group that is registered with ACF Blocks and outputting on a page.

I need this field to also output some schema code in the head of the page when it is used within a page but when I try to access that field in the header.php it doesn't output anything from the field.

I'm using mu-plugins and wondered if that could be an issue?

header.php

```
  <?php
// Get the global variable
global $post;


// Check rows exist.
if( have_rows('block_faq') ):

  // Loop through rows.
  while( have_rows('block_faq') ) : the_row();

      // Load sub field value.
      $question = get_sub_field('question');
      echo $question;

      $answer = get_sub_field('answer');
      echo $answer;


  // End loop.
  endwhile;

// No value.
else :
  // Do something...
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reset_rows();` in header loop, if its works. Otherwise use below code snippet for your `header.php` for schema generate -

```
global $post;
$block_faq = get_field('block_faq');
if ( $block_faq ) :
    foreach ( $block_faq as $key => $faq ) {
        // Load sub field value.
        $question = $faq['question'];
        echo $question;
  
        $answer = $faq['answer'];
        echo $answer;

        // Remove above codes in the those are just example as per your codes
        // Do your schema generation tasks with above data
    }
// No value.
else :
    // Do something...
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

The code above doesn't seem to output anything either.
Where does reset_rows need to go?

Comment: I was just checking acf docs - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/. sorry to say they don't provide `reset_rows()` function. Anyways can you please check that is there any data returning in `$block_faq` from above - `$block_faq = get_field('block_faq');`

Comment: Nothing is being returned but my code at the top is showing on the page, it just doesn't seem to output in the head.

Comment: Make sure you global $post returning data like `$post->ID`

Comment: The below outputs the correct id.
echo $post->ID;

Comment: If I duplicate the field group and use the location rules and assign it to a post type of 'page' rather than block. This works with the code above.